# Cannot run programs in my prison

Tags: prison-architect

I am trying to run a Behavioral Therapy program in my prison and I think I get all necessary requirements. I have a psychologist and a full office empty with many chairs. But the program continue to say that "All Rooms Are Booked".

[image]

How can I solve?

In this screen you can see a free office with chairs and the psychologist office that have to run the Behavioral Therapy.

[image]

And here it is the current Regime.

[image]

Comment: Can you screen shot the applicable room?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to assign more "Work" hours in the regime tab.

If you have a closer look, by default there are only two consecutive work-blocks.
Some programs need three (or more?) consecutive work blocks. So does the educational lesson.

The feedback "ALL ROOMS BOOKED" is not very helpful here, I ran into that, too.

Thank you for confirming it was "work" @Amadeus9.

Comment: Definitely work.

Comment: I tried ti create 3 work bloks still nothing. I added some screen on top to help

Comment: @Drake the work blocks do need to be consecutive. In your example, e.g. Work from 9am to 12pm, you can remove the work block at 5p.m. for that. i have edited my answer to clarify that

Comment: @Drake please also have a look how long the specific program is. I know that some programs exceed the standard distribution of work blocks, but i am not sure if 3xwork will suffice for any program. The tooltip on a program tells you the duration afaik

Comment: Yes the program was 3h long that was the reason it never started. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that this can occur is if you have designated the room in question as staff only.  For example, if all kitchen space is designated as *staff only* no matter how many cookers and work hour slots you have the "all rooms booked" message will always display.  This is resolved by switching them to general access or min/med/max sec from the deployment menu.

Comment: As far as I remember, you get a more specific error message in that case.

Comment: @Philipp I think you're right in the later alphas, my answer has probably been invalidated since the May release when the question was asked

Answer (score 0):

I hope you (or anybody else) are still looking for an answer, because I have one.

I was having the same problem for the longest time. Couldn't find a good answer anywhere. My offices were not designated staff-only and I'd added jail doors to all offices in case inmates couldn't enter through staff doors.

And then I realized;

Draw a fence! Right around the offices. Sometimes, I put the offices outside of the fence without realizing it, but inmates cannot enter an area without a perimeter. As soon as you do this, you should be able to schedule behavioral therapy with no problems.

Hope I helped, and sorry for the late response.

Comment: I do not belive this as the issue in this paticular case. When writing answer, please take in account the whole question post (and possible comments, if relevant), not just the tittle.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is simple: Behavioral therapy only takes place in the psychologist's office. Assign the psychologist to the office and your problem should be solved.